# bash process substitution can't work fine with tee

Tags: linux, bash, tee

The real thing I want to do is like `ps -ef|head -n1 && ps -ef|grep httpd`. The output should be something like this.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
xxxxx     6888  6886  0 16:49 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
root     10992     1  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 sudo ./myhttpd
root     10993 10992  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 ./myhttpd
root     11107 10993  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 ./myhttpd
root     12142 10993  0 14:00 ?        00:00:00 ./myhttpd
root     31871 10993  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 ./myhttpd
```

But I hate duplicates. So, I want `ps -ef` to appear only once.
Considering bash process substitution, I tried `ps -ef | tee > >(head -n1) >(grep httpd)`, but the only output is

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

However, `ps -ef | tee > >(head -n1) >(head -n2)` can work fine in the following way

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 13:36 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/init
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You never actually said what you want to pull? One row of `ps` containing httpd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `head` and `grep` on the same stream.

```
ps -ef | (head -n 1; grep '[h]ttpd')
```

It might be marginally more efficient to refactor to use `sed`:

```
ps -ef | sed -n -e '1p' -e '/[h]ttpd/p'
```

... but not all `sed` dialects deal amicably with multiple `-e` options. Perhaps this is more portable:

```
ps -ef | sed '1b;/[h]ttpd/b;d'
```

Also note the old trick to refactor the regex so as not to match itself by using a character class.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved simply with pgrep and ps.

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -d, -o -f httpd)
```

Answer (score 2):

use AWK

```
ps -ef | awk 'NR==1 || /httpd/'
```

print out 1st line or any line contains "httpd"

or use sed

```
ps -ef | sed -n '1p;/httpd/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -f -C httpd --noheaders | head -n1
```